# Not setting state with data get back from fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I can `console.log(data)` before and after line of the `setState` but not setting state of `confirmationDetail` successfully, but the cart works.

```
placeOrder(information) {
    const init = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(information),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    fetch('api/orders', init)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (!data.error) {
          this.setState(state => ({ cart: [], confirmationDetail: data }));
        } else {
          Swal.fire(data.error);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your state object

Comment: `this.state = {
      cart: [],
      confirmationDetail: {}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I guess using `this` inside a fetch call is problem. At the point that you're trying to call this is actually undefined. 
Can you try following ?

```
    const init = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(information),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    const that = this;
    fetch('api/orders', init)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (!data.error) {
          that.setState(state => ({ cart: [], confirmationDetail: data }));
        } else {
          Swal.fire(data.error);
        }
      });
```

Comment: it's the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
          fetch('api/orders', init)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((findresponse) =>{
                this.setState({
                   cart: [], 
                   confirmationDetail: data
                });
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('api/orders', init)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (!data.error) {
          that.setState({
             ...confirmationDetail,
             confirmationDetail: data,
             cart: []
          });
        } else {
          Swal.fire(data.error);
        }
      });
```